# Running a script if X server haven't been receiving any input for some time

Tags: bash, cron

I want to run a certain script when I'm not around my machine so it would run automatically but it would not bother me when I'm working. I created the bash script and queued it with cron, but it doesn't seem to run (it doesn't produce the required effect of opening a browser tab).

Here is the script located at `/home/suseika/.bin/stackoverflowfanatic`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
idle=`xprintidle` # tells how long in milliseconds x server haven't been receiving any events
required_idle_time=3600000 # one hour in milliseconds
if [[ $idle -gt $required_idle_time ]];
then
        chromium http://stackoverflow.com/
        echo idle was $idle
        xdotool mousemove 12 13 # A quick and dirty way to send an event to x server
        xdotool mousemove 12 14
        echo now idle is `xprintidle` # for debugging
fi
```

The script works fine if I set `required_idle_time` to 0 and run it manually with `sleep 1 && stackoverflowfanatic`

Here is how I queue it with cron:

`/etc/cron.d/stackoverflow`:

```
0,30 *     * * *     suseika /home/suseika/.bin/stackoverflowfanatic
```

Answer (score 1):

Cron doesn't have access to your X session, by design.  You should probably run this in a background loop from your `.xsession` or similar instead.